# Visualization Plug-ins

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

As far an UI and UX are concerned, most posts in *ux.stackexchange* will require users to draw an image or diagram to support their answer. I do not know how practical this suggestion will be, also I can guess how this suggestion will come with plenty of loose ends, but is it possible for us to have **third-party tool** or a **plug-in** to draw diagrams, charts and have features for free-hand drawing? It will save a lot of time for all the members attempting to answer questions.

**Advantage**

- Visually represent answers to the questions, without the usage of external applications to create an image and upload it.
- Easy to edit and modify diagrams.
- Saves a lot of time.
- Improves the quality of the answer.
- Minimal and basic forms of visualization, restricting users with limited colors and features.
- Increase clarity of posts.

As far as disadvantages, or should I say possible roadblocks, it will be pretty difficulty to include plug-ins, and this should be put in Beta for quite sometime.

Although it may seem very hard, I think this would be a very useful tool, much like the provisions of block-codes and pre-compiled code features in SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This already exists. Balsamiq mockups are built into the post editor.

[How do I add mockups and/or visuals to my questions?](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/how-do-i-add-mockups-and-or-visuals-to-my-questions)

[image]

That pencil icon drawing a wireframe - that's the launch for Balsamiq.

Comment: ohh..my bad. I wasn't aware of this feature. Thank You.